# How to convert finished PCB to schematics effectively?

Tags: hardware, pcb

I have a PCB board that is a little involved to figure out its working. I spent a good day mapping trace by trace, node by node but still some node connections wouldn't make sense. I know designers use software to reroute PCB traces, making them compact and planar, also render them hard to decipher.

I was wondering if there is any software that helps me translate single sided PCB traces with components to schematics?

Answer (score 4):

[Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/) will allow you to add parts and create traces in PCB view, creating the equivalent in Schematic view with symbols and "ratsnest" lines representing the traces which you then arrange and fill in with wires.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nice guide while trying to do the same: 
http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-reverse-engineer-a-schematic-from-a-circuit/

Answer (score 0):

[http://www.amazon.com/Art-PCB-Reverse-Engineering-Unravelling/dp/1499323441/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1444060514&sr=8-1&keywords=the+art+of+pcb+reverse+engineering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1499323441)

This book got nice feedback on www.eevblog.com and on amazon.com, I'm not connected with author in any possible way, apart that I own book he wrote ;-)

Answer (score -1):

[Elgris Technologies](http://www.elgris.com) has the tool "E-studio For Test" that can generate OrCAD, DxDesigner and other schematics from a PCB.